# Good Introductory Text for Quantizing Geometry?

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, quantum-gravity, geometry, loop-quantum-gravity

In this [video](https://youtu.be/MgwJmWXoWWI?t=49) she makes an interesting claim. In loop quantum gravity on can think of the gravity as:

$$ G^{\mu \nu} = \kappa T^{\mu \nu} $$

Now in loop quantum gravity one can quantize geometry as well along with the stress-energy tensor:

$$ \hat G^{\mu \nu} = \kappa \hat  T^{\mu \nu} $$

(Author: Prof. Dr. Kristina Giesel; Youtube Title: The Big Bounce, Signs in the CMB? A Loop Quantum Gravity update; Institute: Institute of Theoretical Physics)

### Question

Is there a good introductory text for methods in which they quantize geometry? (including other approaches than Loop Quantum Geometry)

Comment: The geometric quantification program was initiated by Jean-Marie Souriau around 1960 for example   : http://archive.numdam.org/article/AIHPA_1967__6_4_311_0.pdf

Comment: @TheTiler This is in French :(

Comment: Ok, for exemple https://math.berkeley.edu/~alanw/GofQ.pdf

Comment: @TheTiler Your pdf seems to be about the geometry of the phase space and symplectic manifolds and their role in quantization. It is not about quantum gravity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believe it or not, this is quite a broad topic, and depends upon who you ask on what you mean by, ''quantizing geometry.'' Since this term can sometimes *appear* broad, I will also outline the different quantum gravity schemes and attempt to differentiate them from quantum *geometry* schemes:

- String theory: this is *not* a theory of quantized geometry. String theory is essentially taking the worldline of a particle, extending it in one dimension, and anlyzing the worldline (turns into a *worldsheet*) physics (also adding more fields and symmetries to eventually create the 9+1 superstrings we know and love). If you wanted to study strings, I would recommend the textbook [String Theory in a Nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/069112230X) by Kirtsis and use Polchinski's text to fill in some of the gaps (like derivations). For a quick overview of the field then these notes look promising, ''[String theory: a perspective over the last 25 years](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.2569)'' by Mukhi, but they are missing the latest developments of string theory's Swampland program which Palti has the best introduction and review thereof, ''[Swampland](https://inspirehep.net/literature/1725205).''
- Loop Quantum Gravity (LQG): LQG is a theory that quantizes the geometry *directly* and uses the tetrad formalism ($g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{ab}e^a_\mu e^b_\nu$) to quantize the geometry of the metric. Rovelli has a textbook out himself (the newer one) which is here: [Covariant Loop Quantum Graivty](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/110881025X). But, a review by Ashtekar is on arxiv, ''[A Short Review of Loop Quantum Gravity](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.04394).''
- Symplectic geometry: there is currently a field of study that is looking into what quantization *actually means* which involves a field of mathematics called symplectic geometry. The best notes I have found and read/used came from an introduction by John Baez on his website here: [From Classical to Quantum and Back](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2019/01/30/from-classical-to-quantum-and-back/).
- Canonical methods: the original methodology to quantize gravity was to use the normal methods at the time (around 1940's I believe) by stating the commutators the fields should obey. Or, a little more in-depth, finding the Hamiltonian formulation of General Relativity, and then act on a state/wave-function. This way led to the famous Wheeler-de Witt equation, which turned out to be unsolvable (this is where LQG came into play).
  -Miscellaneous theories: the 4-dimensional version of quantizing general relativity has a lot of issues. One way to simplify this is by a dimension reduction to form 2+1 gravity. Steven Carlip is one of the people on the forefront of this research and has a text on it here: [Quantum Gravity in 2+1 Dimensions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521545889). For a good overview of *all* the theories listed above, Claus Kiefer has a text here: [Quantum Gravity](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199585202).
- Others: I know there are a few other methods such as emergent gravity, gauge field formulations, non-commutative geometries, and twistor field theory, which all deal with quantizing geometry itself, but my knowledge is quite limited. Your google search would be as good as mine in finding a resource.

I hope this helps you decide which direction you want to look at!